# Get all records from core data and get string with one attribute from every record (MagicalRecord)

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm try to get all the elements that the user saved inside the app(this could be easy), get one attribute from every record and have these attributes listed inside a string(that's the problem). How can I do it? 
I wrote something but I don't think it is the right way. help me please!

```
 -(NSString*)getAllRecords
{
    NSArray* arra = [NewItem MR_findAllSortedBy:@"data" ascending:YES];
    NewItem* ctn = arra.;// I have not any idea

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arra componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this should do what you want:

```
NSArray *elements = [NewItem MR_findAllSortedBy:@"data" ascending:YES];
NSArray *attributes = [elements valueForKey:@"attributeName"];
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributes componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];
```

Applying `valueForKey:key` to an array returns an array containing the results of invoking `valueForKey:key` on each of the array's objects.

Answer (score 2):

A tad more code, but:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NewItem MR_requestAllSortedBy:@"data" ascending:YES];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"attributeName"];
NSArray *results = [NewItem MR_exceuteRequest:request];

NSArray *listOfValuesOfAttributeName = [results valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.attributeName"];
```

At the end of this, `listOfValuesOfAttributeName` will basically be a single array of the values you're after. This is similar to the following sql "select attributeName from NewItem".

The last `valueForKeyPath:` call is needed because the results returns is a list of dictionaries. What you want is a list of values. The `@unionOfObjects` keypath operator cleans this up for you.